# what exactly is the logic behind 6502 and precise clock cycle emulation?

Tags: c++, emulation

Key questions to consider based on page 10 of this document:

http://archive.6502.org/datasheets/rockwell_r650x_r651x.pdf

- What does page 10 imply by "Add 1 to N if page boundary is crossed"?
- What does page 10 imply "Add 1 to N if branch occurs on the same page?"
- What does it mean by add 2 to N if branch occurs to different page?
- Does read and write to other devices ie.RAM cause any irregularities in clock cycles?
- Are there any other factors that could affect clock cycles on the 6502 (more specifically the NES) ?

Comment: This looks like a question for the hardware experts at the [Electrical Engineering StackExchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=6502). No game developer I know works with this chip in their day to day work anymore, so you might find we're not the ones with the information you need.

Comment: @DMGregory, this is the chip used to emulate the NES.  Which i would argue is the most common game emulator ever made

Comment: I'm aware. And if this were the 1980s, you might find your average game developer has experience with the cycle level details of that chip. We are, however, 30-40 years later, and modern game development does not generally make use of such chips.